# How to run Excel VBA SendKeys in line with the other code

Tags: excel, vba

I separated 2 sub functions (NextStep and AnotherStep) because the SendKeys code will run after the code is done. After I created ImportWorkbooks function, the SendKeys code are now inside a loop, and it will run again after the loop is done.

I used SendKeys because I cannot get the data from the filtered cell. I did my research and somehow SendKeys is the only code that works.

```
Public Sub ImportWorkbooks()
  Dim FNames As Variant
  Dim Cnt As Long
  Dim Wbk As Workbook
  Dim MstWbk As Workbook
  Dim Ws As Worksheet
  Dim I As Integer
   
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False
   Set MstWbk = ThisWorkbook

   FNames = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel files (*.xls*), *.xls*", MultiSelect:=True)
   If Not IsArray(FNames) Then Exit Sub
   For Cnt = 1 To UBound(FNames)
      Set Wbk = Workbooks.Open(FNames(Cnt))
      Wbk.Sheets("Summary").Activate
      Wbk.Sheets("Summary").Copy Before:=MstWbk.Sheets(1)
      MstWbk.Activate
      Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      MstWbk.Sheets("Summary").Activate
      NextStep
      Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      Wbk.Close False
   Next Cnt

   'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Private Sub NextStep()
   'set column AV
   Range("AV1").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _"=IFERROR(CONCAT(RC[-9],""_"",ConcatenateButBlank(RC[-3]:RC[-1])),RC[-9])"
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   Selection.Copy
   Range("AV2").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=AGGREGATE(3,3,C[-47]) - 2"
   Range("AV3").Select
   ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Status & Date"

   Dim Counter As Integer
   Dim Total As Integer
   Dim I As Integer
   Dim RowID As Integer
   
   For Counter = 1 To I
    SendKeys "+({DOWN})"
   Next Counter

   SendKeys "^(v)"
   AnotherStep

End Sub

Private Sub AnotherStep()
   // VBA code...
End Sub
```

Comment: Too much context is missing for being able to help. What's the target of the SendKeys? What is `I`? Currently it looks like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: @VincentG I have updated it :)

Comment: The SendKeys is used to select the filtered cells and paste the formula i have copied from another cell

Comment: First, the `I` in the first function is not the same as the `I` in the second function.
Secondly, you should be able to avoid using SendKey since you can copy paste between workbooks without issues (using something like `Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").Paste Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`)
Thirdly you should be able to make a code clearer bu avoiding Activate and Select, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: `I` is not the issue here, the codes are working fine except for SendKeys. SendKeys works after the loop is done

Comment: It's not the best solution, but if you are stuck with SendKeys, you should give an opportunity for the sent keys to be processed. Try to add [DoEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/doevents-function) after every SendKeys.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no alternatives for fixing SendKeys. I had no option but to find another code that won't use SendKeys.